# Read two JSON files and extract all items present in the second file that are not in the first to a new object

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft to read in two JSON files to objects.

Example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm

```
firstJSON = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\file1.json"));

secondJSON = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\file2.json"));
```

My first JSON is formatted like this:

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
       "sys_id" : "11111111",
       "u_description" : "test1",
    },
    {
       "sys_id" : "22222222",
       "u_description" : "test2",
    }
  ]
}
```

My second JSON is similarly formatted like this:

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
       "sys_id" : "11111111",
       "u_description" : "test1",
    },
    {
       "sys_id" : "22222222",
       "u_description" : "test2",
    },
    {
       "sys_id" : "33333333",
       "u_description" : "test3",
    },
    {
       "sys_id" : "44444444",
       "u_description" : "test4",
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to extract the additions to the array/key value pairs to a third JObject?

My third object should look like this:

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
     "sys_id" : "33333333",
     "u_description" : "test3",
    },
    {
     "sys_id" : "44444444",
     "u_description" : "test4",
    }
   ]
}
```

I am open to any ideas including using Newtonsoft to convert to XML first.
I just want to read the data in the third object/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward approach, assuming the `sys_id` values uniquely identify each item in the `result` array:

1. Get all the `sys_id` values from the `result` array in the first JObject and put them in a HashSet:

   ```
   var sysIds = new HashSet<string>(firstJSON["result"].Select(t => (string)t["sys_id"]));
   ```
2. Loop over all the items in the `result` array in the second JObject and remove the ones that have a `sys_id` contained in the HashSet:

   ```
   foreach (var item in secondJSON["result"].ToList())
   {
       if (sysIds.Contains((string)item["sys_id"]))
       {
           item.Remove();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now the second JObject has only the "additions" remaining, which is what you are looking for.  You can either loop through and process the items, e.g.:

   ```
   foreach (var item in secondJSON["result"])
   {
       var sysId = (string)item["sys_id"];
       var desc = (string)item["u_description"];

       // do whatever you need to do here...
   }
   ```

   Or convert it back to JSON:

   ```
   File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\file3.json", secondJSON.ToString());
   ```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QLYdiV

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to approach this would be deserialize both Json strings, and use Except. For example,

```
var set1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString1).result;
var set2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString2).result;
var comparer = new ResultEqualityComparer();
var set3 = new RootObject
          { 
             result = set2.Except<Result>(set1,comparer)
                          .ToList()
          };
```

Where RootObject is defined as

```
public class Result
{
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
    public string u_description { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

And ResultEqualityComparer is defined as

```
class ResultEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Result>
{
    public bool Equals(Result left, Result right)
    {
        return left.sys_id == right.sys_id && left.u_description == right.u_description;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Result result)
    {
        return result.sys_id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "sys_id": 33333333,
      "u_description": "test3"
    },
    {
      "sys_id": 44444444,
      "u_description": "test4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: FYI, your solution as posted does not produce the correct output-- he wanted `33333333` and `44444444` in the final result, not `11111111` and `22222222`.

Comment: @BrianRogers Thanks , that was dumb of me. I have updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can solve you task by using [Deserialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) and then apply [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2) to deserialized lists

Answer (score 1):

If you are in control of the format of the files, one option is to create corresponding classes/property bags to deserialize into. It would be something very simple like (this is VB.Net but you could do the same thing in C# which it looks like you're using):

```
Public Class MyObject
     Public Property sys_id As String
     Public Property u_description As String
End Class
```

Then in your code it would be something like this:

```
Dim list1 As List(Of MyObject) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyObject))(File.ReadAllText("..."))
```

Once you've got the POCO lists, you can use LINQ to get the exclusion or match or whatever it is you need.

**However**, something like that works best when you know the structure of the result JSON and it's not going to change on you unexpectedly.

If you're not in control of how the JSON is going to come, you can use the [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to do much the same, the disadvantage is that you can't use a strongly-typed object and you will have to be a lot more pessimistic (existence checks, NullReference checks, etc.).